# Simplifying an Expected Value formula

Tags: probability, statistics

Recently I asked a question related to Expected Value over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787888/calculating-average-time-based-on-success-probability).

The case is that interns have to pass to 2 training programs consecutively. Each program has a success rate of 40% ($p$) and each takes 3 months ($t$) to complete. If $c$ is the number of training programs, then the formula for the expected completion time will be:

$$
\large\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=c}^{\infty} (t \times i) \times {i-1 \choose i-c} \times 0.4^c \times 0.6^{i-c}
$$

But then I discovered that the expected completion time can also be calculated by this formula:
$$
\frac {c \times t }{p}
$$

I have tried to run both formulas by using various values of $p$, $c$, and $t$, and the results are always the same. Is there an explanation as to how the first formula can be simplified to the second formula?

Edit: fixed the first formula, and I also uploaded my Excel calculation over [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/bEThE/EV-calculation.xlsx) (the download link is on the top of the page)

Comment: The results are almost never the same. Can you show how you "ran" these formulas?

Comment: Sorry, the previous formula was not correct. I think I fixed it. I'll try to share my Excel file

Comment: No need to, now the formula is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of the identity
$$
\frac{c}{(1-x)^{c+1}}=c\sum_{i\geqslant c}{i\choose i-c}x^{i-c}=\sum_{i\geqslant c}i{i-1\choose i-c}x^{i-c},
$$
used at $x=1-p$. Note that this identity reads
$$
\sum_{i\geqslant c}i{i-1\choose i-c}p^c(1-p)^{i-c}=\frac{c}p.
$$
Finally, the key identity above is obtained by differentiating $c$ times the series expansion
$$
\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{i\geqslant0}x^i,
$$
and dividing by $(c-1)!$ both sides of the result.

Comment: Is there a term or a name for the first equation?

Comment: The series $1/(1-x)$ is the standard geometric series. Its derivatives might be called [negative binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) series (but I fail to see the point).

Comment: I'm trying to understand the theory behind it because I have another similar case which I'd like to simplify. The difference in the second case is that both training programs are taken at the same time instead of consecutively. So the sample for completion time will be $\Omega = \{ 3, 6, 6, 9, 9, 12, 12, \dots \infty \}$ instead of $\Omega = \{ 6, 9, 12, 15 \dots \infty \}$

And I'm not sure how the formula will change for the second case.